# Receiving error code 424 in VBA when attempting to use CopyHere method with built in Windows Zip

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, zip

I am receiving the object required error on the following line, although fl4 is a defined variant/object/file:
`oFold.CopyHere (fl4)`

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Below is an applicable excerpt of code.  I have excluded the recursive loop and directory sub folder iteration:

```
    srcpth = rs1.Fields("Src_File_Path").Value
    destpth = rs1.Fields("Zip_File_Path").Value
    var = 0

    Set FS2 = New FileSystemObject
    Set FS2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fl1 = FS2.GetFolder(srcpth)
    For Each fl2 In FS2.GetFolder(srcpth).SubFolders

        var = 2
        ZipFile = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\tmp\" & fl2.Name & ".zip"
        Set FS3 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        FS3.CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
        Set FS3 = Nothing

            Set FS4 = New FileSystemObject
            Set FS4 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set fl3 = FS4.GetFolder(fl2)
            For Each fl4 In FS4.GetFolder(fl2).Files
                var = 2
                GoTo Zipxchg
zipxchg_2:
            Next
        Next

Set FS1 = Nothing
Set oFld = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
Set oShl = Nothing

Exit Sub

Zipxchg:
If var = 2 Then
    ZipFile = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\tmp\" & fl2.Name & ".zip"

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set oFld = oApp.NameSpace(CVar(ZipFile))
    Set FilestoZip = objShell.File(fl4)
    i = oFld.Items.Count
    oFold.CopyHere (fl4)

    Set oShl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        GoTo zipxchg_2

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Zipxchg:` the target of an `On Error GoTo`?  (If so, you are missing a `Resume`.  Probably `GoTo zipxchg_2` should be `Resume zipxchg_2`)  Oops, no, I see the `GoTo` for it now.  Forget I said anything.  But you are missing an `End If` for the `If var = 2 Then`.

Comment: `fl4` is an object and `CopyHere` expects a variant with a string value. Try adding the CVar() as you did a few lines earlier.  Also eek that `goto` thing is not good.

Answer (score 0):

remove the brackets .... use `oFold.CopyHere fl4`   .... brackets cause a value to be returned, but there is no variable (object) to receive it

Comment: It's VBA in access. Using a recursive loop to zip files within subfolder. Creating each subfolder as a parsed internal zip folder and keeping packets under 2GB for secure data transfer. Back in the day I used to program in Visual Studio, java and jcl/php

Comment: The Goto is to handle multiple cases while still using the same wait for compression. I supposed I could just change it to a public function instead. I don't know why I didn't think about adding back in CVar()... Thank you Tim Williams

Comment: CVar(fl4) still returns 424

Comment: that is not what you said before. you said that the oFold.CopyHere line returned the error 424

Comment: It was in response to another suggestion. Ofold.copyhere fl4 and ofold.copyhere (cvar(fl4)) also returns 424.

Comment: have another look ... do you see any similarity between `oFold.CopyHere (fl4)`  and `oFold.CopyHere (cvar(fl4))`  ????

Comment: Cvar(fl4) also returns the same error. I had checked before your last post

Comment: here is is spoon fed .... it is the oFold.CopyHere (xxxxx) that returns the error